# Text File writer and reader not working on my WPF

Tags: c#

My WPF app crashes whenever I try to click on the write button of my app. The write button is supposed to write a string into a text file and read the string back. I have the string appear on the content section of the write button.

Here is where I think the problem lies.

```
private void Write_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filelocation);
        writer.WriteLine("Welcome to my universe");
       
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filelocation);
       Write.Content= reader.ReadToEnd();

    }
```

The WPF app crashes with no warnings when I try to build and test it. I have tried removing the other sections of the code, and I have determined that the other parts work fine. How do I stop the WPF app from crashing?

Comment: *"How do I stop the WPF app from crashing?"* - Wrap the failing code in a try/catch block to observe and handle the exception.  The first step in fixing any error is finding out what that error is.  The caught exception will have that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the build of the app instead of the debugger to test your code. If you run your code as it is now, you will get an error saying the file you are tying to access is already being used by another process. To fix this you must close the writer before you start the reader with `writer.Close();`This should fix the issue:

```
private void Write_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filelocation);
    writer.WriteLine("Welcome to my universe");
   writer.Close();
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filelocation);
   Write.Content= reader.ReadToEnd();

}
```